# Erro ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException ao executar código

Tags: java, exceção, array

Meu código está dando o seguinte erro:

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 10   at t151.main(t151.java:19)

O que isso significa e como corrigir?

Segue o código:

```
       public class t151 {

        static final int n = 10;

            public static void main (String[] args){

                int A[][] = new int [n][n];

                int i,j;

                    for (i=0; i < n; i++){
                        for (j=0; j < n; j++){

    }
                            System.out.print (A[i][j]);     
}
}
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A linha `System.out.print(A[i][j]);` está fora do segundo laço, e a condição de saída do segundo laço é `j` ser maior ou igual a `n`(que vale 10), o que faz você acessar uma posição inexistente do vetor(tem 10 posições, mas vai de 0 a 9). Por isso o java acusa o `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException`.

Para corrigir, altere conforme abaixo, adicionando a linha mencionada dentro do segundo laço:

```
public class t151 {

    static final int n = 10;

    public static void main (String[] args){

        int A[][] = new int [n][n];

        int i,j;

        for (i=0; i < n; i++){
            for (j=0; j < n; j++){
                System.out.print (A[i][j]); 
            }    
        }
    }
}
```